# i'm getting CultureInfo.InvariantCulture format for MM/dd/yyyy. but i want to get dd/MM/yyyy format what i do that

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the system date and split day,month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986114/get-the-system-date-and-split-day-month-and-year)

getting CultureInfo.InvariantCulture format for MM/dd/yyyy. but i want to get dd/MM/yyyy format and i want to split the day and month and year.

Here is my code :

```
string sDate = string.Empty;
DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(_date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
int count = 0;
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
sDate = dateFormat.ToString(format);
string[] Words = sDate.Split(new char[] { '/' });
foreach (string Word in Words)
{
    count += 1;
    if (count == 1) { Day = Word; }
    if (count == 2) { Month = Word; }
    if (count == 3) { Year = Word; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not get, what you actualy want to achieve from this code, 
if you need day, month and year, 
why dont you go for

```
sDate.Day
sDate.Month
sDate.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the short date format for the invariant culture *is* `MM/dd/yyyy`. If you want to parse with a specific pattern, you should use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int day = date.Day;
int month = date.Month;
int year = date.Year;
```

(I don't know why you're splitting strings in the way you are... your whole question is unclear about what you're trying to achieve...)