# Get the system date and split day, month and year

Tags: c#, asp.net

My system date format is dd-MM-yyyy(20-10-2012) and I'm getting the date and using separator to split the date, month and year. I need to convert date format (dd/MM/yyyy) whether the formats returns at any date format.

```
string sDate = string.Empty;
DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
int count = 0;
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
sDate = dateFormat.ToString(format);
string[] Words = sDate.Split(new char[] { '-' });
foreach (string Word in Words)
{
    count += 1;
    if (count == 1) { Day = Word; }
    if (count == 2) { Month = Word; }
    if (count == 3) { Year = Word; }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985802/im-getting-cultureinfo-invariantculture-format-for-mm-dd-yyyy-but-i-want-to-ge

Comment: If you already have the `DateTime` object, why can't you simply use the properties defined on it? `Year`, `Month` and `Day` should give you the values you need directly. I don't see the point of converting to a string that you then mess around with to extract data that is already easily reached.

Answer (score 22):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
String sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
DateTime datevalue = (Convert.ToDateTime(sDate.ToString()));

String dy = datevalue.Day.ToString();
String mn = datevalue.Month.ToString();
String yy = datevalue.Year.ToString();
```

**OR**

Alternatively, you can use split function to [split string date into day, month and year](http://www.aspneto.com/how-to-split-string-date-into-day-month-year.html) here.

Hope, it will helps you... Cheers. !!

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but do you know what your code snippet does?
Why do you create a DateTime object then call ToString() twice and convert it back to DateTime so you can call ToString() a third time?

All you need is DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @BojidarStanchev Dear I'm expecting date string as an input (though it's DateTime object) as asked by user. So that's only for use case. I don't wanted to bother user with different kind of culture formats at run time. So that was just a basic rule. Main aim was to show how to separate Day, Month, Year easily from date string that's it!

Answer (score 13):

You can do like follow:

```
 String date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
    String Month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    String Year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```

On the place of datetime you can use your column..

Comment: There's a race condition in your example, very close to midnight on some days.

Answer (score 9):

You can split date month year from current date as follows:

`DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now.Date;`

Day:

`int day = todaysDate.Day;`

Month:

`int month = todaysDate.Month;`

Year:

`int year = todaysDate.Year;`

Answer (score 6):

You should use `DateTime.TryParseExcact` if you know the format, or if not and want to use the system settings `DateTime.TryParse`. And to print the date,`DateTime.ToString` with the right format in the argument. To get the year, month or day you have `DateTime.Year`, `DateTime.Month` or `DateTime.Day`.

See [DateTime Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN for additional references.

Answer (score 5):

Without opening an IDE to check my brain works properly for syntax at this time of day...

If you simply want the date in a particular format you can use [DateTime's .ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx). There are a number of examples of standard and custom formatting strings if you follow that link.

So

```
DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
var _dateString = _date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

would give you the date as a string in the format you request.

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR**; The DateTime Object in C# has the ability to extract the string information using the **ToString()** function with the correct format string. (ie: "yyyy-mm-dd");

```
string onlyDateWithoutTimeStamp = lastDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```