# How can I split date and time separate?

Tags: c#

I have a datetime column in mysql db column and I need to show it in separate date and time textboxes.

My datetime format in db is `2014-12-24 17:23:35`. And I want in:

```
Date : 2014-12-24  
Time : 17:23:35
```

How can I do it in c#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should look into DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ...? Do the text boxes need to be editable, or just read-only?

Comment: `My datetime format in db` Databases don't store dates in a "format". To any DB engine it's just a number, and the format depends on how you interpret it client-side afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the system date and split day, month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986114/get-the-system-date-and-split-day-month-and-year). @peer provides a very good answer using built-in functionality.

Comment: @TimS. it is a web page..nd this is for edit page so textboxes should be editable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DateTime dtValue;  // load your date & time into this variable
TextBox1.Text = dtValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
TextBox2.Text = dtValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: how can we load a string in date time variable?

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution is working absolutely fine.

Comment: This is an absolutely worst idea. One should never treat date and time values as strings. The time you will spend formatting and parsing is considerable and potential for errors is substantial. Use controls, which have been build to process date and time values, not TextBoxes.

Comment: I personally don't use text boxes to receive date & time input, however it is perfectly fine to use text boxes as a readonly display of date & time.

Comment: This method is short , simple and sweet ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can retrieve your `datetime` column as a `DateTime` object, and then format it twice - once with a format that ignores the time part, and once with a custom format that ignores the date part.

```
var d = new DateTime(2014,12,26,17,21,30);
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0:d/M/yyyy} Time: {0:hh:mm:ss}", d);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qCCaDr)

or

```
var d = new DateTime(2014,12,26,17,21,30);
var dtPart = d.ToShortDateString();
var tmPart = d.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: You could also use

`DateTime.ToShortDateString();`
`DateTime.ToShortTimeString();`

It makes for much cleaner and more readable code.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, this is simple:

- The [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns just the date part
- The [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns just the time part

Comment: @Jonathaan how can I split it in two different textboxes in c#

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple way of doing it, if you are still having trouble.

```
    var result= "7/26/2017 12:00:00 AM"; // Whatever your variable is
    string[] Separate = result.Split (' ');
    string desiredDate = Separate [0];
    Debug.Log (desiredDate);
```

If you need the time, just create a variable with the second array element.

even you can make your custom format

```
    var result= "7/26/2017 12:00:00 AM"; // Whatever your variable is
    string[] Separate = result.Split (' ');
    string desiredDate = Separate [0];
    Debug.Log (desiredDate); // OUTPUT: 7/26/2017

    string[] SeparateDate = result.Split ('/');
    Debug.Log (SeparateDate[0]); // OUTPUT: 7
    Debug.Log (SeparateDate[1]); // OUTPUT: 26
    Debug.Log (SeparateDate[2]); // OUTPUT: 2017

    // for OUTPUT: 26/7/2017
    Debug.Log (SeparateDate[1]+"/"+SeparateDate[0]+"/"+SeparateDate[2]);
```

Comment: This works like charm. !!!

Answer (score 1):

> My datetime format in db is 2014-12-24 17:23:35

Datetime in a database does not have a format. It is stored in its native binary form. If you only need to display, as in no updates expected, than **use the same database column twice**, while leveraging two string formats, one for just date part, and one for only time part, for example in .Net apps you can use "d" and "t".

Some code for you:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    var dateTimeColumnFromDatabase = DateTime.Now;
%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <%= dateTimeColumnFromDatabase.ToString("d") %></p>
    <p>Time: <%= dateTimeColumnFromDatabase.ToString("t") %></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Of course you have to plug in your database code in place of `DateTime.Now`

If you use any 3rd party controls, they usually have Format property where you can specify the needed formatting for display.

Comment: I cannt take two columns in database .in database it is only one column daqtetime.I need to show it on asp.net page by c# code

Comment: I have not said two columns in the database. Two columns on display, which is what you have asked for.

Comment: @Dqarek but will this code can split database datetime column in date and time sepratley?

Comment: The database datetime column contains both parts of the datetime value, date and time. I am oversimplifying here, because they are not parts per se. During display or edit, you can address them separately or together. If you check .Net docs, you will find out that a DateTime has separate properties for Date and Time, but they are part of the same value of DateTime. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).ToShortDateString(); // For Date
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).ToShortTimeString(); // for time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;               //Gets the current date
string datetime = dt.ToString();          //converts the datetime value to string
string[] DateTime = datetime.Split(' ');  //splitting the date from time with the help of space delimeter
string Date = DateTime[0];                //saving the date value from the string array
string Time = DateTime[1];                //saving the time value

**NOTE:** The value of the index position will vary depending on how the DateTime 
value is stored on your server or in your database if you're fetching from one.

Output: 10/16/2019 1:38:24 PM
        10/16/2019 1:38:24 PM
        ["10/16/2019","1:38:24","PM"]
        10/16/2019
        1:38:24
```